# How to limit Apache response timeout?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, timeout

I have an apache server, and there are lots of connection opened by a user, and it never ends. 
Already ran for 4886 seconds and keeps counting. There are 80 such requests.

The page is simple, and not a download page.

So I have two questions:

- What is the reasonable time to set for apache for: sending reply?
- How to set this for the apache2?

Comment: you need to use iptables to block this users ip address, your under a DOS attack.

Comment: What do the requests look like?  What's recorded in the access log?

Comment: They are fine HTTP1.1 access. It was not a DOS attack, it was from a known user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running an apache version prior to 2.2.21, which means you are vulnerable to the HTTP Range exploit documented in [**CVE-2011-3192**](http://httpd.apache.org/security/CVE-2011-3192.txt) - please read that document on how to remedy.